# Modify property value of the objects in list using Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Fruit` objects in ArrayList and I want to modify `fruitName` to its plural name.

Refer the example:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Fruit {

    long id;
    String name;
    String country;
}

List<Fruit> fruits = Lists.newArrayList();
fruits.add(new Fruit(1L, "Apple", "India"));
fruits.add(new Fruit(2L, "Pineapple", "India"));
fruits.add(new Fruit(3L, "Kiwi", "New Zealand"));

Comparator<Option> byNameComparator = (e1, e2) -> e1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getName());

fruits = fruits.stream().filter(fruit -> "India".equals(fruit.getCountry()))
            .sorted(byNameComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Fruit> fruitsWithPluralNames = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
    fruit.setName(fruit.getName() + "s");
    fruitsWithPluralNames.add(fruit);
}

System.out.println(fruitsWithPluralNames);

// which prints [Fruit(id=1, name=Apples, country=India), Fruit(id=2, name=Pineapples, country=India), Fruit(id=3, name=Kiwis, country=New Zealand)]
```

Do we have any way to achieve same behavior using Java 8 streams ?

Comment: What’s the point of adding the elements to a new list? That list is identical to the original list. For the remaining task, you don’t need a stream: `fruits.forEach(fruit -> fruit.setName(fruit.getName()+"s"));`. By the way, `Lists.newArrayList()` has no advantage over `new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 200, accepted):

If you wanna create new list, use `Stream.map` method:

```
List<Fruit> newList = fruits.stream()
    .map(f -> new Fruit(f.getId(), f.getName() + "s", f.getCountry()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you wanna modify current list, use `Collection.forEach`:

```
fruits.forEach(f -> f.setName(f.getName() + "s"))
```

Comment: @SergeyLagutin and @Apostolos thanks for your reply.  `Collection.forEach` loop is nice and quite simple to use. 

As I have just updated my question (added filter and sort on list using streams). Do we combine plural name functionality with filter and sort ? or we need just again separate `Collection.forEach` ?

Comment: @BhaveshDangi sort action will be done in plural list. you can combine them, yes. please also dont forget to accept an answer. thnx

Comment: Any performance difference between using Streams and forEach in this case?

Comment: It seems there's a small typo in the answer.  shouldn't  ".map(f -> new Fruit(f.getId(), f.getName() + "s", f.getCountry())" line have one more closing ")" at the end

Comment: @Sergii Lagutin Can we update multiple fields, ex name as well as the country in a single for each loop?

Comment: What about if you do not want to change the original list, just to set one value for one specific object and keep the rest as original?

Answer (score 33):

You can use just `forEach`. No stream at all:

```
fruits.forEach(fruit -> fruit.setName(fruit.getName() + "s"));
```

Comment: Can I set `name` and `country` both using this?

Comment: yes but not with one liner. you need to use `{` `}` and add insider all the setters with `;`

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `peek` to do that.

```
List<Fruit> newList = fruits.stream()
    .peek(f -> f.setName(f.getName() + "s"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Peek method should only be used for debugging. 

API Note:
This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline:

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: I don't understand why this operation is "mainly" for debugging. I don't understand why Java API would have code "mainly" for debugging. The operation is there and can be used for whatever the developer thinks it fits. Of course, the developer has to understand how it works and use it properly. For this question, forEach is a better answer, but for when you want to continue the stream, peek is a better fit (forEach doesn even work in that case).

Comment: @Jordan Silva: I would use map() rather than abuse peek(): map(f -> { f.setName(f.getName() + "s"); return f;})

Comment: @RonMcLeod in my opinion the use of `map` in this situation is semantically wrong. Besides that, you need extra code to make it work.

Comment: For me, using peek for such an operation does not seem right. Every functional programmer will see map and understand what it does. Peek (as in stack operations) is mainly for seeing the current status but not changing it as the meaning applies (if we are not quantum computing :) ). As the API documentation for peek shows, it is there to show intermediate level results for debugging. You could do it with map but that would mean you have some intention changing something on the list, where you actually you dont.

Comment: @JordanSilva no need to use stream here (hence no peek), a simple foreach is sufficient to modify the list as the question is asking

Comment: @gaetan224 as I said in my first comment ;)

Answer (score 5):

just for modifying certain property from object collection you could directly use forEach with a collection as follows

```
collection.forEach(c -> c.setXyz(c.getXyz + "a"))
```

Comment: this does not work when adding to a list (if 'c' is a List<>) I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: This is the right way. forEach can do it to the current list where as in Streams, you have to do the work-around of returning a new list.

Comment: Foreach didnt modify the list

Comment: @Rishi this is the right solution

Answer (score 3):

We can change the property via map without creating new objects.
Below method increase the age by 2. It will modify your original list

```
List<Employee> l2=list.stream().map(t->{
                t.setAge(t.getAge()*2);
                return t;
            }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using streams map function like below, get result in new stream for further processing.

```
Stream<Fruit> newFruits = fruits.stream().map(fruit -> {fruit.name+="s"; return fruit;});
        newFruits.forEach(fruit->{
            System.out.println(fruit.name);
        });
```

Comment: A simple foreach then modify the name on the list is sufficient, no need to stream

Answer (score 2):

You can use map from streams.

```
fruits.map(i-> {
   i.setFruit();
   return i;
 }).collect(Collectors.toList();
```