# Replace in a Arraylist with more Columns

Tags: java, arraylist

So for an assignment i need to to replace an Element in an ArrayList. As an example i have a Team Class

```
class Team {
  int id, int points;
  String name;
}
```

I need to find the ID of the Team in the List and replace the Points with new Points. I know i can get the index of the ID with list.get(i).id but i don't know how to replace the Points there. I know that there is a list.set() command but i didn't find how to replace the Points of the Team in the ArrayList because the set Command doesn't accept "i" as a Parameter. 
Already thanks in advance

Comment: it's not clear, what you want to do, replace a Team by Teams or change points attribut of a particular team?

Comment: You can see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496455/modify-property-value-of-the-objects-in-list-using-java-8-streams

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an ArrayList of Team objects and you want to change the points of a team with a specific id?

In order to do this, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourlist.size(); i++)
 if (yourlist.get(i).id == yourID)
    yourlist.get(i).points += 1;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the list will be a `Team`. As you said, first you need to get the element `Team` that has the ID of the `Team` you want to change the points of. To do this, you need to somehow iterate over the list and find that such element(s). Watch out, as [`List<T>.Get(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) will give the element present at index `i` of the list, not the `Team` with ID `i`. Then, to set the points of the `Team`, either assign a value directly, or, better yet, define and use [setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work) methods. [`List<T>.Set(int i, T elem)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) replaces the `Team` at index `i`, for the `Team elem`, so it shouldn't be what you want to be doing, as `points`, the thing you want to change, can be changed directly on the instance already present in the list. To use `Set`, you'd have to create a new `Team` instance with a new value for `points`.