# Update element in the list while iterating Java8

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, java-8

I have `List` of `Customer` object. I want to iterate over list and increment orders by one.

I tried with for each but here I had to create new list and add values in it.

```
class Customer{
    long id;
    int orders;
    //getters setters constructor
}

List<Customer> empList=Arrays.asList(new Customer(1,10),new Customer(2,,20));

List<Customer> empList1=new ArrayList<>();
empList.forEach(e->{
    e.orders++; //updating orders
    empList1.add(e);
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? I tried with streams but it is only mapping the orders

```
empList.stream().map(e->{e.orders++;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you can use `peek`

Comment: You don’t need to create an another list emp1 as you are not modifying the structure of the list you are modifying the existing elements which is an object in this case. As you are using foreach which is a consumer in this case. Your fix should be e.setOrders(e.orders += 1). Then it will just update the existing list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify property value of the objects in list using java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496455/modify-property-value-of-the-objects-in-list-using-java-8-streams)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `peek`

```
empList.stream().peek(e->{e.orders++;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also as correctly pointed by "Vasanth Senthamarai Kannan " you don't need second list as you are not modifying structure of list,

```
empList.forEach(e->e.orders++);
```

Comment: Or shorter: `empList.forEach(e -> e.orders++);`

Comment: @Holger.. Yes.. Appreciate your feedback

Comment: Peek method should only be used for debugging https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replaceAll()` just define a method like `incrementOrder()`

```
empList.replaceAll(Customer::incrementOrder);


  public Customer incrementOrder(){
    this.orders+=1;
    return this;
  }
```