# How can I use a map to modify existing elements in a stream?

Tags: java

I have an object I searched for and said object is stored in a stream. I'd like to give the user the ability to modify the elements within the existing stream and update the existing list with the modified elements, instead of creating a new list altogether. The question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496455/modify-property-value-of-the-objects-in-list-using-java-8-streams), except the user is adding the modified elements to a new list

Here's what I have so far. I'm currently getting this error

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'void', 'void'

If you need the entire code, or the inclusion of other classes, please let me know.

Main Class

```
else if (choice == 2){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the movie you would like to modify (Case Sensitive): ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            Optional<Item> item = items.stream()
                    .map(x->{
                        if(x.getItems()==null){
                            return Collections.singletonList(x);
                        }
                        x.getItems().getItem().add(x);
                        return x.getItems().getItem();
                    })
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
                    .peek(x-> x.setItems(null))//Peek exists mainly to support debugging
                    .findFirst();
            System.out.println(item.toString());

            System.out.println("\nEnter the new datatype of the movie (Number): ");
            String userChoice = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the new name of the movie: ");
            String userChoice1 = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the new data ID for the movie (Number): ");
            int userChoice2 = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the new group for the movie: ");
            String userChoice3 = scan.nextLine();

            Collection::stream =
                    item.map(s -> s.setDataType(userChoice) + s.setName(userChoice1) + s.setData(userChoice2) + s.setGroup(userChoice3));
        }
```

Items Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

Item Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
    }

    public String singleObject(){
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the Item class?

Comment: @marc Item and Items class(Just incase) were posted

Comment: For your information, class `Items` references class `Item` and class `Item` references class `Items`. This is known as a _circular dependency_ and should be avoided.

Comment: The reference was to deal with parsing the nested objects within another object. Is it still bad in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your main function you ask the user to provide the name of the movie and then about the fields to modify. So after asking the user all the questions, you can use the following operation:

```java
items.stream()
     // search for the movie by name
     .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
     .findFirst()
     // if present then modify it
     .ifPresent(i -> {
        i.setDataType(userChoice);
        i.setName(userChoice1);
        i.setData(userChoice2);
        i.setGroup(userChoice3);
        i.setItems(null);
        });
```

In this way the list is modified in place.

Comment: I see, I made a previous post asking what was the best way to go about this and was given the advice to use map, hence my approach above. Thank you, I'll try it and see how it works

Comment: Yes, in general you use ```map``` to create a new list and ```forEach``` to modify a list in place. But in your case there is only one element to modify so instead of ```forEach``` you can use ```findFirst``` and ```ifPresent```.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you meant by there's only one element to modify. The list contains multiple objects (movies), each containing the fields that I asked the user for.  So the user can choose whichever movie they'd first like to modify and then go ahead and modify it, but yes, only 1 movie at a time can be modified. Here's the link to my [github](https://github.com/SodeshDindayal/Jaxb) containing the xml file showing the structure

Answer (score 1):

In `item.map()` statement you are calling setter which returns void hence you are getting issue. Void is not valid return type for map method. + Operator can also not be applied to void operand.

Couple of observations

1. `if(choice == 2)`

- Here you should do only one task of modifying the movie present in the list, if movie is missing in the list inform user about this.

2. `Items class` contain `List<Item>`

- now no need to add Items inside Item class.

Below is the sample code I tried

> It finds the movie name entered by user in Items and modifies it there
> instead of creating a completely new list.

```
. items.getItem().stream()  
.filter(x -> x.getName.equals(search))
.forEach(x -> {x.setName(userInputName); x.setDatType(userInputDataType)});
```

Comment: I tried this, but using a getter I'm not able to enter the user input as the argument, `item.map(s -> s.getDataType(userChoice)` where userChoice is not an expected argument

Comment: In functional terms what are you trying to achieve ? And what that particular line is meant to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the values of the elements in the stream. To do so, the user must first enter the new values. After which, those values must be collected and mapped onto the existing values located in the stream, thus, modifying the old values to the new user inputted one. That particular line is meant to take the new user input and pass them to the elements to have them changed

Comment: couple of observation
1) if(choice == 2) here you should do only one task of modifying the movie present in the list, if movie is missing in the list inform user about this.
2) Items class contain List<Item>, now no need to add Items inside Item class.
Anyway below is the sample code I tried, it find the movie name entered by user in Items and modifies it there instead of creating a completely new list. Hope it does the job for you.

items.getItem().stream().filter(x -> x.getName.equals(search)).forEach(x -> {x.setName(userInputName); x.setDatType(userInputDataType)});

Comment: Thank you. I edited your original answer and added in the code from the comment. Hope this helps someone else who may come across it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have written very complicated code. Couple of Observations :

1. if(choice == 2) here you should do only one task of modifying the movie present in the list, if movie is missing in the list inform user about this instead of adding it.
2. Items class contains List of Item, now no need to add Items inside Item class unless these are Entity classes which you want to persist in DB.

Anyway below is code snippet, hope it helps.

```
items.getItem().stream().filter(x -> x.getName.equals(search)).forEach(x -> {x.setName(userInputName); x.setDatType(userInputDataType)});
```